# How do I add multiple conditions to disable a textarea in angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is what i tried but doesn't seem to work as expected. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to use it with on a reactive form.

```html
<textarea
              nbInput
              fullWidth
              formControlName="departureComment"
              rows="5"
              disabled = "valid || checked || dep"
            ></textarea>
```

There is the form in typscript

```
this.checkpointPassageForm = this.fb.group({
  checkPoint: [this.data?.checkPointId],
  waybill: [this.data?.waybillId],
  arrivedAt: [this.data?.arrivedAt],
  departureAt: [this.data?.departureAt],
  arrivalComment: [
    { value: this.data?.arrivalComment || "Everything is ok", disabled: true },
  ],
  departureComment: [
    {
      value: this.data?.departureComment || "Everything is ok",
      disabled: true,
    },
  ],
  firstPassage: [this.data?.firstPassage],
  details: [
    {
      value: this.data?.details || "No additional Detail",
      disabled: false
    },
  ],
});

this.initData();
```

}

Comment: Are `valid`, `checked` and `dep` all booleans?

Comment: You will have to explain a little bit more on what ````valid, checked and dep```` are. Are those boolean values or are those the same formControl or are those some other formControls??

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<textarea
  nbInput
  fullWidth
  formControlName="departureComment"
  rows="5"
  disabled = "{{valid || checked || dep}}"
></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea
  nbInput
  fullWidth
  formControlName="departureComment"
  rows="5"
  [disabled] = "valid || checked || dep"
></textarea>
```

However the first one will convert the expression to string, therefore will always result in disabled control. So the second one is preferred here

Comment: i tried both but none of it worked for me. Just forgot to mention i am trying to use it on a reactive form.

Comment: @Faouzi where do the valid, checked and dep props come from?

Comment: they all come from different back-end responses.

Comment: dep , checked and valid are boolean wish are modified by back-end responses. I'm using those on a button and it works great and since the textarea is also related to the button I want it to work the same. That is, when the button is disabled the textarea also should be disabled and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should use property binding syntax, like this:

```
[disabled] = "valid || checked || dep"
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkhrsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks for responding but binding syntax doesn't seem to work in my case.